# How zoom into a Textbox

Tags: java, android, xml

I was wondering if it would be possible for my application to zoom into a textbox when selected. Since the application is meant for people who are generally older, I would like this to be a possible option. Also to let you all know, this isn't related to anything about WebView. The application is simply a set of textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Zoom in When *SELECTED*?** [There is a class on github by](https://github.com/JadeByfield89/ZoomableEditText/blob/master/src/com/aquarius/zoomedittext/ZoomEditTextView.java)  **@JadeByfield89** which extends the  EditText and make it *pinch Zoomable* .

**CODE ZoomableEditText**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by Jade Byfield on 3/29/2014.
 */

// ImageView that draws a grid on top of it's canvas
public class ZoomEditTextView extends EditText {

    // touch tools
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    // The Ôactive pointerÕ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint mCirclePaint;
    private Path mCirclePath;
    private Paint mDrawingPaint;
    private List<Path> mPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private List<Paint> mPaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    private float mBrushSize = 12.0f;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private Paint mRectPaint;
    private Context mContext;

    public ZoomEditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();

    }

    public ZoomEditTextView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();

        // this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        //
        // @Override
        // public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        //
        // InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext
        // .getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        //
        // return true;
        // }
        //
        // });

    }

    private void init() {

        // Create our ScaleGestureDetector
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(mContext, new ScaleListener());    

        // Sets up drawing tools
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePath = new Path();
        mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mCirclePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

        //

        mDrawingPaint = new Paint();

        mDrawingPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mDrawingPaint.setDither(true);
        mDrawingPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mDrawingPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mDrawingPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mDrawingPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mDrawingPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBrushSize);

        mRectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)    ;
        mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRectPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        mDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        // setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        // buildDrawingCache();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save();
        //
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        // canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(),
        // canvas.getHeight()), mRectPaint);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        // if (mBitmap != null && canvas != null) {
        // canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mPosX, mPosY, mPaint);
        // }

        canvas.restore();

    }

    // Listen for multi-touch drag event and redraw the view accordingly
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);    

        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {

        // a touch down
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            // Scale detector is not in progress
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                // Save the ID of this pointer
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

                // Remember where we started
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                // Save the ID of this pointer
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

                break;

            }
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            // Only move the image if the scale detector is not in progress
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                // Find the index of active pointer and save its position
                final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // mBitmap = getDrawingCache();

                // Calculate the distance moved
                float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                // Move the object
                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                // Invalidate to request a redraw
                invalidate();

                // break;

            } /*
             * else {
             * 
             * final float gx = mScaleDetector.getFocusX(); final float gy =
             * mScaleDetector.getFocusY();
             * 
             * final float gdx = gx - mLastGestureX; final float gdy = gy -
             * mLastGestureY;
             * 
             * mPosX += gdx; mPosY += gdy;
             * 
             * invalidate();
             * 
             * mLastGestureX = gx; mLastGestureY = gy;
             * 
             * }
             */

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            // Reset the active pointer id
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
            final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;

                if (event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
                    mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                }
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);

            } else {
                final int tempPointerIndex = event
                        .findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                mLastTouchX = event.getX(tempPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = event.getY(tempPointerIndex);
            }
            break;

        }

        }

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```